# Genexus - how to set Google Chrome as default browser?

Tags: genexus

I'm new in Genexus development. I would like to know how to set google chrome as default browser when the Genexus application run?

Thank you in advance for those who answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Genexus uses your system default browser when running a webpanel or the web developer menu. That is, the browser that opens by default when you for example enter a url in the windows run dialog.
To change your default browser to chrome, you normaly only need to open chrome and choose the "Set as default browser" option. I've just found [this chrome help page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417?hl=en) that explains how to achieve just that.
I hope this helps, and that I did not misunderstood your question.